# how to transfering division on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-animations

Hi everyone  I hope you have a good day
my div element that has bootstrap col class wasn't transferred to the right by CSS animation correctly and I'm not able to click the button that is under the div
please help me   thanks
[image: this is the picture]

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 form">
</div>
```

```
.slide {
    animation: slide 2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: put more html code

Answer (score 1):

You have set inline style with bootstrap for the div layout (from mobile to xl). The HTML code under the parent (the divs you speak of) would be more helpful in explaining the problem, as it is not so clear.

Otherwise, I think you may have to remove the class and use JavaScript to add it, on click of the button.